# void function c++ error this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

Tags: c++

why there is an error This declaration has no storage class or type specifier at ReadFile??

```
void ReadFile(ifstream &in, std::map<std::string,std::set<std::string>> &m)

{
    while(true)
    {
        std::string word;
        in>>word;
        if(!in.good())break;
        m[signature(word)].insert(word);
    }
}

int main(){
    std::ifstream in("ospd.txt");
    std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> m;
    ReadFile(in,m);
}
```

Not sure whether the ifstream in (filename) is correct... Any ideas?

I found one of the mistake... there should be a std:: before ifstream. However, it still not work. Any clue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<map>
#include<set>
#include<string>


void swap(char &ch1, char &ch2){
    char tmp=ch1;
    ch1=ch2;
    ch2=tmp;
}

std::string ToLower(std::string s){
    for(int i=0;i < s.length();i++)
    {
        if(s[i]<='Z' && s[i]>='A')
        {
            s[i]-='A'-'a';
        }
    }
    return s;
}

std::string signature(std::string s)
{
    s=ToLower(s);
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {   int minIndex=i;

        for(int j=i+1;j<s.length();j++)
            if(s[j]<s[minIndex]) minIndex=j;
        swap(s[minIndex],s[i]);
    }
    return s;
}

void ReadFile(std::ifstream &in, std::map<std::string,std::set<std::string>> &m)
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::string word;
        in>>word;
        if(!in.good())break;
        m[signature(word)].insert(word);
    }
}
typedef std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>>::const_iterator MapIterator;
 typedef std::set<std::string>::const_iterator SetIterator;

int main(){
    std::ifstream in("ospd.txt");
    std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> m;
    ReadFile(in,m);


for (MapIterator iter = m.begin(); iter != m.end(); iter++)
{
    std::cout << "Key: " << iter->first << std::endl << "Values:" << std::endl;

    for (SetIterator set_iter = iter->second.begin(); set_iter != iter->second.end(); set_iter++)
        std::cout << " " << *set_iter <<std:: endl;
}

    system("pause");
return 0;}
```

Comment: Please provide the full error message.

Comment: Since it appears you aren't doing `using namespace std` (good!) the first parameter needs to be qualified with `std::`

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Compiles fine here: http://ideone.com/tGSO17 (I've added a dummy implementation of `signature`).

Comment: Functions reading a stream shouldn't travel in terms of `std::ifstream` but rather use `std::istream`: this way they can be used with `std::cin`, an instance of `std::istringstream`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't include any of the headers required for `std::string/map/set/ifstream`, nor did you qualify the use of `ifstream` with `std::`.

Comment: my header includes: #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<map>
#include<set>
#include<string> @LuchianGrigore